# D3 - get selected Date range on brushend

Tags: d3.js

I am new to d3 and using brushing on grouped bar chart

http://fiddle.jshell.net/CjaD3/21/

I am trying to get the range selected. I am listing to the "brushend" event and calling a function brushend(). Its getting called but returning me the x-axis coordinates in numbers ([42, 318]). I want in Date dormat like 'Sat 25' to 'Mon 27'

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is where you would usually use a the `invert` method of your x-scale.  Unfortunately, [that method doesn't exist](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/pull/598) for ordinal scales.  Luckily, Jason Davies, [patch is still around](https://github.com/jasondavies/d3/commit/443720422ce7f1dcdc9dc7e909a7bb41fa2a65f1).  I don't like messing with the source, so I adapted it for your function:

```
function brushend() {
    console.log("brushend");

    var b = brush.empty() ? contextXScale.domain() : brush.extent();

    console.log(b);
    var d = mini_x0.domain(),
      r = mini_x0.range(),
      startDate = d[d3.bisect(r, b[0]) - 1],
      finDate = d[d3.bisect(r, b[1]) - 1];

    console.log([startDate, finDate]);
}
```

Updated [fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/CjaD3/22/).